# How to catch the request Header in Java using HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I want to catch a header in java. The code I have written is correct. Still, it's coming as null. Can you please suggest the changes. I am doing this task in interceptor. Is there any annotations that I missed on a controller class or any configurations that I need to do on controller class??

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jose4j.jwk.HttpsJwks;
import org.jose4j.jwt.JwtClaims;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.JwtConsumer;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.JwtConsumerBuilder;
import org.jose4j.keys.resolvers.HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

@Configuration
@Component
public class TokenValidateInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {

        String apiKey;
        System.out.println("Header  "+request.getHeader("xx"));  //Null
        System.out.println("request  "+request);  // request  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4df9ffc7
        System.out.println("request.tostring  "+request.toString()); // request.tostring  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@e0770ef
```

[I am passing the header using POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmo0D.png)

Comment: Try printing out all of the headers.  That should help debug the issue.

Comment: I am sending only 1 header by the name `xx`

Comment: The `sysout` are followed by the content its printing

Comment: I'm just saying print all of the headers out to see if you're getting anything at all.  If you aren't, then you've confirmed there's something definitely wrong with your configuration.

Comment: Yes i ry to print `content-type` it's also coming as null

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh `Content-Type` is not a required header and the fact that it's `null` is not an indication your code is wrong.

Comment: See @luc14n0 answer below.  If you have configuration problems I would be much more likely to expect you would get a null HttpServletRequest object than one with all blank headers. But you're definitely getting an HttpServletRequest object.  Possible that postman isn't sending exactly what you think it is?

Comment: @D.L. ditto. Try using `curl -H 'xx: test' localhost:8080/servlet` instead of POSTMAN to make sure you're correctly passing the header.

Answer (score 2):

The 'xx' header is probably not present in the request.

Replace

```
System.out.println("Header  "+request.getHeader("xx"));
```

with

```
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println("Header  " + headerNames.nextElement());
}
```

to see all the headers the server receives from the client.

Comment: @Anand Any luck with the same!

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe even better.  Might be nice to see the value too:

Replace:

```
System.out.println("Header  "+request.getHeader("xx"));
```

With:

```
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String header = headerNames.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Header  " + header);
    System.out.println("Value  " + request.getHeader(header)));
}
```

Comment: I Updated the code `Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
  System.out.println("Has more elemet "+headerNames.hasMoreElements()); //False
  while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      System.out.println("Header Enum  " + headerNames.nextElement());
  }` hasMoreElement itself coming false